# Assigning using ternary operator?

Tags: perl, variables, ternary-operator

I am on Perl 5.8 and am needing to assign a default value. I ended up doing this:

```
if ($model->test) {
    $review = "1"
} else {
    $review = ''
}
```

The value of `$model->test` is going to be either `"1"` or undefined. If there's something in `$model->test`, set `$review` to `"1"` otherwise set it equal to `''`.

Because it's not Perl 5.10 I can't use the new swanky defined-or operator. My first reaction was to use the ternary operator like this...

```
defined($model->test) ? $review = "1" : $review = '';
```

but that didn't work either.

Does anyone have an idea how to assign this more efficiently? 
Janie

Comment: You should really set it to `!1` not to `''`. They both have the same string representation (`''`). The only difference is that `''` will warn if you try to use it as a number, where as `!1` wont. ( Assuming you always have `use warnings;` at the top of every piece of Perl code like you should. )

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I'd usually write this as:

```
$review = ( defined($model->test) ? 1 : '' );
```

where the parentheses are for clarity for other people reading the code.

Comment: Thanks Greg! I feel odd for even asking because it seems like it would be this simple. (and it is!) JW

Comment: @JaneWilkie Actually, it’s easier than that, even. See my answer.

Comment: Of course the WAY better answer would be to change MySQL's definition to CHAR(1) instead of BIT(1), but sadly the politics of changing something this simple in our production environment are huge.

Comment: @Greg The extra parentheses only hurt readability, in my opinion.

Comment: There is no need for the `defined` in this answer. Plus it could cause the code to break in the future if the method starts returning `''` or `0` instead of `undef`.

Comment: @BradGilbert The OP clearly indicated that the valid values for the call are `1` and `undef`. I do agree that there is some scope here to remove the ambiguity around defined-but-invalid return values such as `0`; however, I disagree that this ambiguity should be removed by merely boolean-testing the return value. This is particularly relevant under `use warnings`, where the variant you imply will reliably cause a warning whenever `undef` is returned.

Comment: That was true on the one example (removed), but that was not the one I recommended. That (removed) example would have also warned if the true value became a string, so it was perhaps the worst example. The one I recommended is `my $review = !! $model->test;` which is as short as you could possibly get, and still show that the intent of the return value is True/False. Also what you have here should be shortened to `$review = defined $mode->test`.

Answer (score 26):

You have a precedence problem. What you have is the same as

```
( defined($model->test) ? $review="1" : $review ) = '';
```

You could make it work with parens.

```
my $review; defined($model->test) ? ( $review='1' ) : ( $review='' );
```

But it's much cleaner to move the assignment out.

```
my $review = defined($model->test) ? '1' : '';
```

---

Moving along, there's no point in checking if the value is defined at all. Seeing as the only two possible values are `undef` and the string `1`, a simple truth test would do.

```
my $review = $model->test ? '1' : '';
```

In fact, since you want true values unchanged, you could simply use the following

```
my $review = $model->test || '';
```

Finally, do you really need to change `undef` into to an empty string? If not, you can simply use the following:

```
my $review = $model->test;
```

Comment: Thinking about it I wonder: Given `a ? b : c` are `b` and `c` evaluated depending on `a`, or are both evaluated to some temporary register each, and the value being used depends on `a`? This makes a big difference when `b` or `c` have a side effect (as in the question). I think most users expect *only one* of `b` and `c` being evaluated.

Comment: @U. Windl, (This would have been better as a Question.) It uses [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), meaning it only evaluates what's necessary. This is even true for `E1 || E2`, `E1 or E2`, `E1 && E2` and `E1 and E2`, which is why we can do `open(...) or die(...)`.

Comment: It is ;-) https://stackoverflow.com/q/69089489/6607497

Answer (score 12):

> `$model->test` is going to be either `"1"` or undefined. If there's something in `$model->test`, set `$review` to `"1"` otherwise set it `''`

Then just use this:

```
$review = $model->test || "";
```

Comment: Tom and Foy in the same thread. Where's Larry Wall? I want us all lined up so I can have my picture taken with you guys.

Answer (score 8):

Besides the conditional operator, I often like to use `do`, which returns the value from the last evaluated expression:

```
my $review = do {
     if( ... ) { 'foo' }
  elsif( ... ) { 'bar' }
  elsif( ... ) { 'baz' }
  else         { 'defaut' }
  };
```

Comment: That is a little overkill in this case. It's always worth adding another technique to your toolbox though, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that `$model->test` is supposed to return a true or false value.

Unless it specifically states that the false value is `undef`, the method could be rewritten to start returning some other false value instead.
Which would break anything that only checks if the value is defined.
( I think it is a bug that the method returns `undef` instead of the canonical false value. )

So the best way to set `$review` is to test the truthfulness of the returned value; not it's definedness.

```
my $review = $model->test ? 1 : '';
```

I would like to point out that this still has a bug in it.
If you want to be able to use the value as a number, it will emit warnings if it was false.

To fix that you should return `!1` (canonical false value), which will return a value that is the string `''`, but also has the numerical value of 0.

```
my $review = $model->test ? 1 : !1;
```

Notice that it could be simplified to just:

```
my $review = !! $model->test; # invert it twice
```

---

If you only want to change the value only when it is false, you could use the or operator [`||`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#C-style-Logical-Or).

```
my $review = $model->test || !1;
```

---

If you really only want to know if it is defined, or not why don't you just use [`defined`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html).

```
my $review = defined $model->test;
```

---

If you want to change the value only when it is undefined, and you have Perl 5.10 or newer you could use the [defined-or operator (`//`)](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-Defined-Or).

```
my $review = $model->test // !1;
```

On an older Perl, that would require more than one [statement](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html).

```
my $review = $model->test;
$review = !1 unless defined $review;
```

Comment: I like the double inversion in this case. It ensures a boolean regardless of what might actually be returned from $model. Concise, yet clear IMO.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, "That didn't work either" is not the most helpful thing you could tell us.  It's important to know exactly *how* it didn't work: what did it do, what did you expect, and how to they differ?

But the problem with

```
defined($model->test) ? $review="1" : $review='';
```

is operator precedence.  The conditional operator `? :` binds more tightly than the assignment operator `=`, so the above is equivalent to:

```
(defined($model->test) ? $review="1" : $review) = '';
```

So if `$model->test` is defined, it does the equivalent of

```
$review = "1" = '';
```

You can fix that problem with parentheses:

```
defined($model->test) ? ($review="1") : ($review='');
```

But really, why would you want to?  The conditional (ternary) operator is useful when you want to use the result.  If the result is going to be discarded, as it is here, it's clearer (and, as you've seen, less error-prone) to use an if/else statement:

```
if (defined($model->test) {
    $review = "1";
}
else {
    $review = "";
}
```

or, if you insist on writing it on one line:

```
if (defined($model->test) { $review = "1"; } else { $review = ""; }
```

If you really want to use a conditional expression, you can do this:

```
$review = defined($model->test) ? "1" : "";
```

which is probably a reasonable way to do it.

**BUT :**

The `defined` operator itself yields either `"1"` (true) or `""` (false). so the whole thing can be reduced to:

```
$review = defined($model->test);
```

Comment: What if `undef` is just a false value, and the method gets re-written to return `''` or `0` as a false value?

Comment: @BradGilbert: Then I suppose you wouldn't want to apply `defined` to it. You obviously need to know what the method returns in order to be able to use it.

Comment: It's not the job of test() to provide values suitable for every other use and it would be bad form to rely on that. That sort of stuff leads to tight coupling and hard tests.

Answer (score 1):

```
my $result = defined $model->test ? '1' : '';
```

Comment: That sets `$result` to nearly the same value as just `$result = defined $model->test;`. The main difference being that your's will warn if used as a number.