# Perl - What is this statment doing?

Tags: perl

I am guess that this line:

```
  my $last = $last_game ? 1 : 0;
```

Is assigning `1` to `$last` if `$last_game` is `true` otherwise `$last` gets `0`. Am I correct?

Thanks

Comment: yes correct, why you don't try it, btw you are assigning simply integers not string `1` not `'1'`

Comment: Although if you are interested to assign `0,1` ,then you could simply do like: `my $last = $last_game || 0;`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is trivial YES|NO question.

Comment: Here is a [**GIFT**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8933031/assigning-using-ternary-operator) for you.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan `$last_game` might not be a boolean, so `my $last = !!$last_game;`

Comment: @mpapec Nice!!.. I am from [tag:C] background.

Comment: if `$last` is just going to be used as a boolean, you may as well skip this and just use `$last_game` as the boolean. Or if you really need to save it in a different variable, then just `my $last = $last_game;`

Comment: @mpapec - This is perl. Everything is a boolean. Or, rather, anything can be a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct, it's a ternary conditional operator.

From [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Conditional-Operator):

> Ternary "?:" is the conditional operator, just as in C. It works much like an if-then-else. If the argument before the ? is true, the argument before the : is returned, otherwise the argument after the : is returned. For example:

```
printf "I have %d dog%s.\n", $n,
    ($n == 1) ? "" : "s";
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a [ternary Conditional operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Conditional-Operator). It works like

> COND ? THEN : ELSE

*If the condition COND is true, only the THEN expression is evaluated, and the value of that expression becomes the value of the entire expression. Otherwise, only the ELSE expression is evaluated, and its value becomes the value of the entire expression.*